# How to filter and delete artifactory repos not updated since 2 years

Tags: repository, artifactory, data-cleaning, artifactory-query-lang

I would like to filter all repos not updated since 2 years. How is that possible?

Comment: Hi. SO is not a code writing service, please provide more detail on what you've tried already.

Comment: I´ve tried to find a possibility doing this at the user interface, but didn´t find a way. Is there any possibility to filter "unused" repos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each repository have a creation date as part of its info:
[image]
 Therefore, you can use the [Artifactory Query Language (AQL)](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+Query+Language) to search for the list of repositories 'older than'.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I´ve solved it via the REST API with the "notUsedSince"-query on artifact-level. Your solution should work to find repos "older than", but don´t fix the "last updated"-problem. Nevertheless, the REST API solution on artifact-level sufficient as well.